# Где папка Account MVC ASP NET Visual Stadio for MAC?

Tags: macos, asp, asp.net-identity-3, .net, visual-studio-for-mac

Всем привет!

В Mac OS  создаю проект MVC  командой dotnet new mvc -o  -au Individual

Все прекрасно работает!
Доступна регистрация и логин пользователей.
Регистрация, например, доступна по адресу https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Register

Логин по адресу https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Login

Но ни контроллера, ни View я нигде найти не могу...

В папке Identity есть папка Pages - в ней только один файл _ViewStart.cshtml с содержанием:

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Нужно просто поменять кое-что на странице логина и регистрации - а найти их я просто не могу... Нету их...
Как все работает не пойму.

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло вот это:

dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc bot5.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login;Account.Logout"

И файлы появились, теперь их можно редактировать!